# C programming If statement variable change

Tags: c

Later on in my program I want to print out the destination that the user has chosen here, how do I do this?

```
void create(){
    char name[200],from,to;
    int age;


    printf("Please enter your name :\n");
    scanf("%s",&name);
    printf("Please enter your age :\n");
    scanf("%d",&age);   
    printf("Pick your current destination");
    printf("\n1 for London\n2 for Manchester\n3 for Brighton\n4 for 
Liverpool\n4 for reading\n5 for coventry\n");
    scanf("%s",&from);

    if(from == 1){
        printf("Select your desired destination %s",&from);
        from =("London");
```

Comment: What do you mean? You mean storing it somewhere for later use outside the function?

Comment: This is a bit odd. You are prompting the user to enter an integer for their selected destination. But you're scanning the input (`from`) as a string using `"%s"`, `from` is defined as a single character (`char`), you are comparing it to the value `1` (`from == 1`) to decide whether to prompt them to fill `from` with a string (which will crash since `from` is a single character), and then assigning `from` the pointer to a static string `"London"`. So I think you have bigger problems than just figuring how to print the destination later.

Comment: If you have a small, fixed set of destinations, you can put them into a `char *destinations[];` array as static strings and then just save the number (index) of the destination in your program as a reference to it. As an aside, semantically, would `to` be a *destination*, not `from`?

Comment: Download gcc, compile with warnings enabled, fix the bugs that it points out to you.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you mean

```
scanf( " %c", &from );
       ^^^^^

//...

if( from == '1' ){
            ^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

In short, if you want to access the **local** variable `from`, declared **inside** the functoion `create()`, it is not possible *[you can hope the variable lies in the same address after the function has returned and try to access that same address in hope that the value is still there but this is **UB**]*.

Waht you can do is to declare it globaly, or return it from the function

```
// option 1) global variable
char from;
int main(){
    ... create(); // don't declare from inside the function, because it is already declared globaly
    // do something with from
    ... }

// option 2) return from function - need to change the create function to return the from variable
char from;
int main(){
    from = create();
    // do something with from
    ... }
```

Note that you're using `scanf / printf` incorrectly:

- `scanf("%s",&from);` should be `scanf("%c",&from);` since from is `char`, not `char[]` or `char*`
- `printf("Select your desired destination %s",&from);` should be `printf("Select your desired destination %c",from);`

Comment: Not to mention the subsequent `from = ("London");` in the OP's code...

Comment: or `if(from == 1){` instead of `'1'` which is not an error, but I guess it's not what OP meant... lots of mistakes to go around. I just picked 2

Comment: `char from;` and `from = ("London")` is definitely an error no matter how you look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Here...The program doesn't have any variable for the location.... It means you can't fetch data to print from no where.... So the program must have the data in program in itself.... if not..... No source no data....

If you want to continue the program as it is... You can use switch statement and display the value later as:

```
switch(from){
case 1:
     printf("London\n");
     break;
case 2:
     printf("Manchestar\n");
     break;
case 3:
     printf("Brigeton\n");
     break;
default:
     //(default Option);
}
```

You can also use character array.
for eg:

```
int from;
int location[3][10]={"London","Manchestar","Brigeton"};
printf("\n1.London\n2.Manchestar\n3.Brigeton");
printf("\nChoose whose city do you want to visit: ");
scanf("%d",&from);
printf("You have choosen %s",location[from-1]);
```

In this way, we can give choice to end user and also we can fetch data directly...